# Как сделать редирект с http://site.ru/home/ на http://site.ru/ ?

Tags: редирект, .htaccess

Как сделать редирект с http://site.ru/home/ на http://site.ru/ ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Простой редирект (в файле .htaccess или httpd.conf для Apache).
>
> `Redirect 301 / http://www.you.com/new.htm`
>
> где `Redirect 301` - это инструкция, говорящая, что страница перемещена. `/` - означает, что все с верхнего уровня сайта, включая все подкаталоги, будет переадресовано. `http://www.you.com/new.htm` - новая страница или сайт (не забывайте поставить последний "`/`", если переадресация идет на сайт).
>
> Чтобы переадресовать только страницу, сохранив PR старой страницы:
>
> `Redirect 301 /old/old.htm http://www.you.com/new.htm`
>
> где `/old/old.htm` - путь и имя старой страницы.
>
> Аналогичный синтаксис для переадресации сайта:
>
> `RedirectPermanent / http://www.you.com/`
>
> Пример переадресации каталога:
>
> `RedirectPermanent /old-directory http://www.domain.com/new-directory/`
>
> Например, зашедших в test переадресуем на `www.test.com`, остальных на `enter.test.com (порядок следования записей важен):
>
> `Redirect permanent /test    http://www.test.com/
> Redirect permanent /        http://enter.test.com/`

[Источник](http://sb-money.ru/article.php?a=75), в нем есть еще способы редиректа.

Answer (score 2):

```
RewriteRule /home.* / [L]
```